# I am confused why intents cannot be called in the fragment class

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Hello everyone I hafidsr, I am new to Kotlin, I do not know why my Intent cannot be called and when this is replaced with context still error, I use recylerview in fragment but when I use Intent in fragment the Intent is not called

FilmFragment.kt

```
class FilmFragment : Fragment(){

private lateinit var filmViewModel: FilmViewModel

private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter

companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() =
        FilmFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                // putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount)
            }
        }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    arguments?.let {
        // columnCount = it.getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    filmViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FilmViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_film, container, false)
    val linearLayout: LinearLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.linear_home)
    filmViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        linearLayout.background
    })


    return root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    val items = listOf(
        Model("Start Wars", "blalalal", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Conjuring", "Film bla bla", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 03", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 04", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 05", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 06", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 07", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 08", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 09", "Source", R.drawable.film_1),
        Model("Content 10", "Source", R.drawable.film_1)
    )

    adapter = MyAdapter()
    adapter.replaceItems(items)
    recylerViewFilm.adapter = adapter
}



class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var items = listOf<Model>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.row_film, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]


        holder.titleTv.text = item.title
        holder.descriptionTv.text = item.desc
        holder.imageTv.setImageResource(item.image)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val model = items.get(position)
            var gTitle : String = model.title
            var gDescription : String = model.desc
            var gImageView : Int = model.image

            val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title",item.title)
            intent.putExtra("desc",item.desc)
            intent.putExtra("image",item.image)
        }
    }

    fun replaceItems(items: List<Model>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    inner class ViewHolder(override val containerView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView),
        LayoutContainer {
    }
}
```

}

why my intent is red, and when this is replaced with context it still gets an error

```
val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title",item.title)
            intent.putExtra("desc",item.desc)
            intent.putExtra("image",item.image)
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the nearest-most wrapping class, which in this case is the OnClickListener itself, which is not a Context. You can't pass `context` here because your class `MyAdapter` doesn't have a `context` property and is not an inner class of your Fragment. You can get a Context reference from a View, such as the view passed to your click listener. Since you have omitted the view argument from your lambda, you can pass `it.context` to the Intent constructor. Or you can be more explicit, for clarity:

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { view ->
        val model = items.get(position)
        var gTitle : String = model.title
        var gDescription : String = model.desc
        var gImageView : Int = model.image

        val intent = Intent(view.context, AnotherActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("title",item.title)
        intent.putExtra("desc",item.desc)
        intent.putExtra("image",item.image)
    }
```

Other alternatives would be to make your MyAdapter an inner class of your Fragment so it could access the Fragment's `context` property, or add a Context property to your MyAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```kotlin
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    val model = items.get(position)
    var gTitle : String = model.title
    var gDescription : String = model.desc
    var gImageView : Int = model.image

    val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("title",item.title)
    intent.putExtra("desc",item.desc)
    intent.putExtra("image",item.image)
}
```

I would do

```kotlin
holder.itemView.apply {
     val model = items.get(position)
     var gTitle : String = model.title
     var gDescription : String = model.desc
     var gImageView : Int = model.image

     val intent = Intent(context, AnotherActivity::class.java)
     intent.putExtra("title",item.title)
     intent.putExtra("desc",item.desc)
     intent.putExtra("image",item.image)

     setOnClickListener {
         startActivity(intent)
     }

}
```

This second version does what Tenfour04 says and creates your intent inside the view. It then launches the activity inside the onClickListener.

Comment: when I try your advice, the intent is still error .

Comment: but when I change the code like this: setOnClickListener {
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }
I did not experience an error but the function did not work

Comment: What is happening when it is not working? 

Is it staying on the same fragment? 

Is it going some place unexpected? 

Are you seeing anything in logcat?

Comment: yes it remains in the same fragment, does not move to the next fragment

Answer (score 0):

Please paste this code your intent will be called..

```
val intent = Intent(context, AnotherActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("title",item.title)
                intent.putExtra("desc",item.desc)
                intent.putExtra("image",item.image)
    context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: now there is no error but when clicked it does not move to the next fragment, remains in the same fragment, does not move to the next fragment

Comment: if you want to open fragment from previous fragment then this code is not for that purpose